# Does the following definition describe a class of manifolds?

Tags: manifolds

I know that there is a very formal definition for "manifold" out there.  However, I'm working within the confines of a first course in multivariable calculus.  I was wondering if the following statement is true:

Let

$$x = f(q_1, q_2) \in \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$y = g(q_1,q_2)\in \mathbb{R}$$

be functions such that:

1. $q_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and

2.

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial q_2}\\\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial q_2}\end{bmatrix}$$

is invertible everywhere.  Then these two equations describe a manifold.

Is that correct?  If so, I suspect that it describes an extremely limited subset of all manifolds, but I'll take what I can get.  If it is not correct, can someone please let me know why?

Comment: Do you mean that the graph $F:=(f,g)$ is a surface if $J(F) \neq 0 $? If so, then the inverse function gives you a local diffeomorphism between an open ball $B((x,y);r)$ about $(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$, which is a patch for a surface. Then you need to work on the overlaps, and show that they are smooth, or at least continuous if you just want a topological manifold.

Comment: I see.  If I require that $f$, $g$ be invertible, I assume that I then don't need the Jacobian condition, is that right?

Comment: I don't know if the two are equivalent, or if this is sufficient; let me think. Do you know the result that the level set of a non-critical point is a manifold?

Comment: The general result is that if a is a regular value of F, then $F^{-1}(a)$ is a submanifold of the ambient space, by the inverse/implicit function theorem.

Comment: I see.  So then, if I let $x - f(q_1,q_2) = 0$ and $y - g(q_1,q_2) = 0$ and assumed that the inverses of these new functions exist, then I have a manifold?

Comment: In each case, yes, if 0 is a critical value, then each map ( the set of points describing the inverse) separately defines a manifold. What I am not sure about is for non-scalar maps, i.e., vector valued maps ( meaning $\mathbb R^k; k=2 $ or higher), this is true if  J(f) is invertible, not sure it is enough for invertibility of functions alone. You can see, e.g., for $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1 $, computing its differential, that 0 is not a critical value. This implies, by the theorem, that $F^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold , the circle. I am just not sure if this is true for maps into $\mathbb R^2$ or higher.

Comment: Ah, I see. So both f and g separately would define manifolds with this definition, but it may be the case that the points (x,y) do not lie on a manifold? However, isn't it true that the Cartesian product of two manifolds is a manifold?

Comment: Yes, but the set {$(f(q_1,q_2), g(q_1, q_2))$}  is not the same as the Cartesian product of the two functions.

Comment: It is an interesting question, will get to it when I have time from work.

Comment: Thanks. All I really need is a reasonable definition that describes some class of manifolds that is accessible to second year students as a brief introduction to the concept. It can be extremely restricted.

Comment: A way of seeing that makes sense to me is that you're gluing together pieces, say open sets of Euclidean space using "nice-enough" maps. Any such gluing produces a manifold.

Comment: 1. Assuming $f$ and $g$ are continuously-differentiable, those two equations (interpreted as conditions on Cartesian $4$-space with coordinates $(q_{1}, q_{2}, x, y)$) describe the graph of a regular mapping (or "immersion") $F:\mathbf{R}^{2} \to \mathbf{R}^{4}$. This set is not generally a manifold (e.g., there can be self-crossings, as in a figure-8), but when restricted to sufficiently small pieces of the domain, the result is a smooth $2$-manifold. 2. Invertibility of $f$ and $g$ do not guarantee the Jacobian condition; think of $(x, y) = (q_{1}^{3}, q_{2}^{3})$ at the origin.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: is there any way to restrict my functions' domains so that I can be assured that I get a manifold?  For example, could I say "let $f$ and $g$ be defined on some domain $q_1 \in [a, b]$, $q_2 \in [c,d]$ such that $f$ and $g$ are bijective on that domain"? Or is there a lot more to it and I just can't get the type of definition I'm looking for?

Comment: @MSIS Logically, then, if I sufficiently restrict my domain I to avoid needing to glue anything together, would that work?  I know I'm looking for an absurdly small subset of manifolds, so do let me know if such a set is so trivial as to be not worth mentioning...

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Can I say that  the inverse image ( level set) of a regular value of a map into $\mathbb R^k $  is a manifold, or does this hold only for k=1?

Comment: @MSIS: Briefly, "yes in general". In detail, if $F:\mathbf{R}^{n+k} \to \mathbf{R}^{k}$ is continuously differentiable, and if for some $y$ in $F(\mathbf{R}^{n+k})$ the derivative $DF(x)$ has full rank $k$ for every point $x$ in $F^{-1}(y)$, then the level set $\{x : F(x) = y\}$ is a smooth $n$-manifold. (The key technical tool is the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).)

Comment: @Michael: My apology: My first comment was incorrect. If $F:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^{2}$ is continuously differentiable, then the graph defined by the equations $(x, y) = F(q_{1}, q_{2})$ in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ _is_ a smooth $2$-manifold. (I was wrongly thinking you'd defined a general immersion from $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{4}$; a graph immersion is special enough that technical snags I mentioned do not arise.)

Comment: Great. So then is my original statement correct, provided f and g are continuously differentiable? Or is it sufficient for them to be differentiable and I don't need any restrictions on my Jacobian?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky: Yes, using the Jacobian condition, since we can set up  $F:=(f,g) $ as $F^{-1}(0,0) $ and , by construction, $(0,0)$ is a regular value ( any value is) , so its inverse image the graph of , $F:=(f,g)$, describes a manifold.